# How to pass multiple query string in window. open in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass multiple queries in `window.open`.
I'm able to send one variable in query string,
but while sending two variables.
Invalid data going through URL

```
  Response.Write("<script>");
  Response.Write("window.open('NewQuote.aspx?val=" + this.txtQuotationNo.Text +"  &uid= + this.uniqueid','_blank')");
  Response.Write("</script>");


o/p NewQuote.aspx?val=KST-HYD/15-116/001/G%20%20&uid=%20+%20this.uniqueid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the quote marks:

```
Response.Write("window.open('NewQuote.aspx?val=" + this.txtQuotationNo.Text + "&uid=" + this.uniqueid + "','_blank')");
```